# postgresql 8.0 fetch start of hour based on timestamp

Tags: sql, database, string, postgresql, datetime

I am using **postgresql 8.0** wherein I have a column which is a timestamp in milliseconds from epoch (but stored as text in table). I want to identify the start of hour for this timestamp. I am unable to think of clean way to do

**Table structure**

```
id (varchar(52)) | Name(varchar(100)) | UpdateTime (varchar(20))
1                | Robin              |  1598051512000
2                | Sally              |  1628734800000
```

My thought process was to use `to_timestamp()`. However it does not accept a BigInt. So the idea was to use `substring()` to discard the last 3 characters of the value in `updateTime` and then pass it to to_timestamp()

e.g. using `select substring('1598051512000', 1, length('1598051512000') - 3));`

However this seems to be getting convoluted. IS there a cleaner way to get start of hour based on timestamp?

Expected Output for input

```
1598051512000  =  2020-08-21T23:00:00Z
1628734800000  =  2020-08-12T02:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use date arithmetics, then `date_trunc()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    date_trunc(
        'hour', 
        date '1970-01-01' + '1598051512000'::bigint / 1000 * '1 second'::interval
    ) UpdateHour
from mytable t
```

Comment: I get an error - `Invalid operation: column "sec" does not exist in the table t.`
Looking at doc for make_timestamp (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html), the signature looks different for the one suggested above.

Comment: @learningMyWayThru: my  bad - it looks like this syntax is available for `make_interval()` only. I changed my answer.

Comment: @GMB . . . You should be able to add `'1 millisecond'` and not need any division.